NextAuth With MongoDB Works On Atlas But Not On Local
I'm building an app with nextjs 14 and I'm using nextauth for logins with mongodb adapter.
After installing mongodb community and linking the URI in .env I tried logging in with a few accounts but no collections were created in the cluster.
To troubleshoot, i made a quick atlas database and linked it instead of the local one, while that fixed the issue, it's not what I need, so is there a way to make it work with the local database?
